# Using function integer arguments with my C++ program

Tags: c++, function, integer, arguments

I have a little project to do, I've created a program that when the user types a number, it will say if it's even or odd. I even used a function. Here's my question:

How do I use integer arguments in a function for the program? (My program *does work*, it just doesn't use integer arguments.)

**Instructions**

Write a C++ function that accepts an integer argument, determines whether the passed integer is even or odd, and displays the result of this determination. (Hint: Use the % operator.)

Make sure your function is called from main(). Test the function by passing various data to it.

**My code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void oddEven() //My Function  
{ 
    int num;

    cout << "Please enter a number " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    if (num % 2)
    {
        cout << "It's odd" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's even" << endl;
    }    
}

int main() //Main program    
{    
    oddEven(); //Calling my Function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to search for information on [functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, yes I did - hence why I'm here.

Comment: @Geos59 _"yes, yes I did - hence why I'm here. "_ Apparently not enough research, and not in the obvious sources: [Declaring functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void oddEven(int num/*num is integer argument*/){
    if (num % 2)
    {
     cout<<"It's odd"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"It's even"<<endl;
    }
}
int main() //Main program
{   int x;
    cout<<"Please enter a number "<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    oddEven(x); //Calling my Function
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, I still need more practice with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void oddEven( int num ) //My Function  
{ 
    if (num % 2)
    {
        cout << "It's odd" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's even" << endl;
    }    
}

int main() //Main program    
{        
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter a number " << endl;
    cin >> num;
    oddEven(num); //Calling my Function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you actually plagiarizing the other answer, or is this just an incident?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , this is clearly my own version of the code. I was editing the OP's code when the other answer was posed, so I didn't even see it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Sometimes you're just late, but usually I'm notified about other answers appearing on the question, even while I'm editing. This could have significant delays (especially on mobile devices).